# what is happening in AddAuthentication identity function? how its say accesstoken in valid?

Tags: identityserver4

I want to know what is happening in AddAuthentication identity function. How it is verifying requested AccessToken is valid for this request?Is this function will call the Accesstoken created identity server and check this accesstoken is created in particular server only?

Comment: Check the source code, its public.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, JWT validation consists of several parts:

- protocol-required parameters validation
- signature validation
- additional payload validation

Protocol requires to check the *issuer* (who created the token) and *audience* (who may accept the token) plus the *validity time interval*.

Signature validation consists of talking to Identity Provider to get its public key, and validation of the encrypted part of the token. Signature guarantees that once created token has not been changed after. Signing is not encrypting, that's why SSL is required to provide the privacy.

After all that passed, any custom behavior, such as claims-based policy check, can take place.

For any additional information please read the [specifications](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation) or the sources directly.

All above is about JWT, *reference tokens* provided and handled by IdentityServer is the completely other story. When using *reference*, the validation procedure takes place on Identityserver side. However the validation result can be cached by the client.